# Найти а[i+1]—наименьшее число больше a[i], в котором нет цифр из a[i]

Tags: алгоритм, числовые-последовательности

Числовая последовательность {a<sub>n</sub>} строится следующим образом: a<sub>0</sub> = 1, для любого i ≥ 0 число a<sub>i+1</sub>, больше a<sub>i</sub>, равно наименьшему натуральному числу, в десятичном представлении которого нет десятичных цифр ai. По номеру i вывести ai.

**Так будет выглядеть последовательность**:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 22, 30, 41, 50, 61, 70, 81, 90, 111, 200, 311, 400, 511, 600, 711, 800, 911, 2000, 3111, 4000, 5111, 6000, 7111, 8000, 9111, 20000, 31111, 40000, 51111, 60000, 71111, 80000, 91111, 200000...

**Как реализовать это? Или хотя бы основной принцип подскажите**,
мучаюсь уже 3 дня, а сдавать завтра

Comment: Ну то есть требование такое: "a[i+1] - это **наименьшее** натуральное число, **большее a[i]**, в десятичном представлении которого нет десятичных цифр a[i]"

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 22, 30, 41, 50, 61, 70, 81, 90, 111, 200, 311, 400, 511, 600, 711, 800, 911, 2000, 3111, 4000, 5111, 6000, 7111, 8000, 9111, 20000, 31111, 40000, 51111, 60000, 71111, 80000, 91111, 200000... Начиная с `200` поведение последовательности стабилизируется.

Comment: Ого, понял, а как это можно вычислить по формуле или алгоритмично?

Comment: Я не понимаю из условия, почему 20 нельзя, а 30 - можно.

Comment: 20 нельзя, потому что предыдущем есть нули уже

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а, перечитал условие. Сначала неправильно понял.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напишите метод, который вернет следующий элемент последовательности по предыдущему:

```
static int Next(int current)
{
    // Запоминаем все цифры, которые есть в текущем числе
    var digits = current.ToString().Distinct().ToList();
    // Увеличиваем число на 1 до тех пор, пока в новом числе встречаются цифры из входного
    while ((++current).ToString().Distinct().Intersect(digits).Any());
    // Пересечений по цифрам нет, возвращаем результат
    return current;
}
```

Остается только вызвать его нужное количество раз:

```
int n = 20;
int a = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) a = Next(a);
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

---

Если требуется вычислять `a` для больших индексов, то можно придумать решение O(1) (верно?). Как заметил в комментариях @AnT, в последовательности есть "стабильные" участки, можно этим воспользоваться так:

```
static string GetA(int index)
{
    if (index <= 9) return (index + 1).ToString();
    if (index == 10) return "22";
    if (index <= 17) return (index - 8).ToString() + ((index - 1) % 2).ToString();
    if (index == 18) return "111";
    return ((index - 3) % 8 + 2).ToString() + new string((char)((index - 1) % 2 + '0'), (index - 3) / 8);
}
```

Например, `GetA(4321)` вычисляется мгновенно и возвращает:

> 800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Проблема в том, что это необходимо реализовать в псевдокоде или блок-схеме. А такие штуки там провернуть не получится.

Comment: Ну простите, изначально вы просили C#-код, блок-схему уж самостоятельно нарисуйте. Комментарии к методу добавил, можете взять их для словесного описания алгоритма.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Ну ведь неэффективно же...

Comment: @Qwertiy, зато просто и понятно и делает именно то, что просят в условии

Comment: @Qwertiy, оптимизировал ;)

Comment: Ага, вижу :) Я тоже думал формулу по индексу сделать, но пока ещё её не придумал. Что-то у тебя в ней if'ов многовато...

Answer (score 3):

Начало последовательности - до `200` - можно сохранить в явном виде. А с `200` и далее последовательность ведет себя периодично-предсказуемо: первая цифра равна `(i - 3) % 8 + 2`, а за ней следует либо `(i - 3) / 8` нулей (для нечетных `i`), либо столько же единиц (для четных `i`)

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long ai(unsigned i)
{
  static const unsigned long long prefix[] = 
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 22, 30, 41, 50, 61, 70, 81, 90, 111 };

  if (i < 19)
    return prefix[i];

  i -= 3;

  unsigned long long v = i % 8 + 2;
  for (unsigned p = i / 8; p > 0; --p)
    v = v * 10 + i % 2;

  return v;
}

int main()
{
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    std::cout << ai(i) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: a(0)=1 по условию

Comment: @Андрей NOP: Точно. Я почему-то решил, что нумерация с единицы. Подправил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function next(/* string */ s) {
  // преобразовать строку в массив
  var a = [...s]

  // отметить использованные символы в словаре
  var used = Object.create(null)
  for (var ch of a) used[ch] = true
  
  // найти минимальный свободный символ
  var ch = 0
  for (ch = 0; ch <= 9; ++ch)
    if (!used[ch])
      break
  
  // Попробовать увеличить первый символ
  if (++a[0] == 10) {
    // если не вышло, добавляем ещё один в начало
    a.unshift(ch)
    
    // лидирующих нулей быть не должно, ищем следующий символ, если добавили 0
    if (ch == 0)
      while (++a[0]<=9)
        if (!used[a[0]])
          break
  }
  
  // все остальные символы заменяем на минимальный
  for (var q=1; q<a.length; ++q) a[q] = ch
  
  // собираем из массива строку
  return a.join("")
}

// выводим первые 50 чисел
var s = "0"
for (var q=0; q<50; ++q) console.log(s = next(s))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```